# How to get text of selected item of drop down in Asp.net MVCrazor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a drop down when i select any item it sends its id to Model while i want to send Selected item's Text.How can i do that ?Here is my code that sends Id of selected item and i am also posting code of the method to get selected item.please help me where i am wrong

View

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="site-label">Assign to</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AssignedTo, (ViewBag.DispatchersList) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AssignedTo)
</div>
```

Controller

```
public static object GetSelectListWithSelectOption(dynamic model, int selected, string valuefield, string textfield, bool addSelect = true, string addSelectValue = "-1", bool performSort = false)
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = null;
    if (model != null)
    {
        selectList = new SelectList(model, valuefield, textfield, selected).ToList();
        if (performSort)
            selectList = selectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    if (addSelect)
        selectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = Cygnus.Library.Resources.General.txtSelect, Value = addSelectValue, Selected = true });
    return selectList;
}
```

Comment: Then make the `Text` property and the `Value` property of the `SelectList` the same - `selectList = new SelectList(model, textfield, textfield)`. Note there is no point adding the 4th parameter - your are binding to a property so its just ignored.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but this is the most pointless code i have seen in a long time. Your method creates a `SelectList` but you return it as `object` meaning you need to cast it again. Your method accepts `dynamic` but `SelectList` accepts `IEnumerable` meaning you could throw an exception. The parameter `int selected` is pointless because its ignored when you bind to a model.

Comment: Parameters `addSelect` and `addSelectValue` show no understanding of how a `SelectList` is used and means you cant even use a basic `[Required]` attribute on your model properties (your generate the label option using the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` - not my manually adding a `SelectListItem` with value `"-1"`. Just use the built in methods. `SelectList sl = new SelectList(db.Items.OrderBy(i => i.Name), "ID", "Name")`

Comment: And in the view use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AssignedTo)` assuming your property has `[Display(Name = "Assign to")]` or `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AssignedTo, "Assign to")` so your create a proper label - i.e. when you click on it, its sets focus to the the dropdownlist

Comment: Dear @Stephen Muecke i am quite new in MVC and this method is written by my senior so i think it is ignore able at this time

Comment: Just pass this link to your "senior".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send the text back, just fill the `Value` property of the `SelectListItems` with the same value that you provide to the `Text` property.

```
public static object GetSelectListWithSelectOption(dynamic model, int selected, string valuefield, string textfield, bool addSelect = true, string addSelectValue = "Selected Item Text", bool performSort = false)
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = null;
    if (model != null)
    {
        selectList = new SelectList(model, textfield, textfield, selected).ToList();
        if (performSort)
            selectList = selectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    if (addSelect)
        selectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = Cygnus.Library.Resources.General.txtSelect, Value = Cygnus.Library.Resources.General.txtSelect, Selected = true });
    return selectList;
}
```